# how to remove black background of 3D image in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, 3d, background

I want to remove the black background. Actually, i have removed the background of the image, but it is replaced by black background as shown in the attached image. i applied 'image segmentation' to the image. what should I do?

[image]

Comment: What do you mean remove then? create a non, square matrix? Try, instead of replacing it by zero, replacing by `NaN`. Does that work for you?

Comment: you can set the first row of your colormap to [1 1 1], to get white background instead of black.

Comment: Either one of the above approaches will work